# Adjusting images in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a 100 page graphic novel in Indesign and I need to apply an adjustment of the Brightness and Contrast of every image in the file to accommodate the quirks of a particular printer. This is an output function. I do not want to edit the original images just to accommodate this particular printer. I want to tell Indesign 'adjust the contract of all images x amount' for example. Is this possible?

Comment: printer = machine or printer = print provider?

Comment: print provider.  Amazon CreateSpace to be precise. They're printing everything VERY dark and their advice to me was 'so brighten everything up'.

Comment: i doubt you can do this as you outline it. One solution might be to copy all the images to a folder and batch alter them, linking them in to your document. Keep the originals in another folder. But i am no expert on InDesign.

Comment: That seems strange. You'd think adjusting every image with some global settings to accommodate the quirks of whatever output device you're aiming for would be quite a common thing.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, other than perhaps altering color profiles in a PDF.. but not in InDesign.

Comment: Hello Ryan, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: It looks like submission to CreateSpace is via PDF. There *is* a convert color to destination when exporting PDF...

Comment: Other than its (spiritual) ancestor PageMaker, InDesign has no facilites to edit images. You could use [Copy All Links](http://indesignsecrets.com/copy-all-your-linked-images.php) to gather themminto a single folder and then batch process with Photoshop or another image processor.

Comment: There are some things you 'Could' do in Indesign, but other than using the correct color profile they won't be easy. - If you really need to adjust all the images, use Benteh's suggestion and batch them in Photoshop, then relink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be so easy if you are using Adobe Lightroom beside Indesign.

Simply make a collection into Adobe Lightroom and batch adjust your collection or adjust images one by one and save.
the saved images will reflect immediately into Indesign. and export to that particular printer.
if you want to revert to the original images, all you have to do is to access your collection again through Lightroom and remove all setting you did before.

That's it.

You don't have to copy the collection manually from folder to another, Lightroom is doing the job to you and keep history of all setting you did in your collection, that's mean you can apply the setting again.